# Inconsistent webhook delivery of Twitter Account Activity API

Tags: api, twitter, webhooks

I have successfully set up a DM bot with the Account Activity API. Everything works very well, except that sometimes the message sent to the bot (through the Twitter's web interface or mobile application) doesn’t fire a webhook to my server. The messages could be quick replies responses or plain text.

The reason is obviously not a downtime of my server since I tried to make a conversation between 2 webhook registered users (so my server receive the webhooks for both users) and for the same message sent, I have successfully received the webhook of the sender (the user) but not for the recipient (the bot).
As the bot isn’t in production yet, the reason is not an overload of messages. There is currently only 2 users that make conversations. From my experience, around 10% of messages are "lost".

I'm using the free (sandbox) Account Activity API tier, but as I understand the only differences between the free and paid versions are a higher number of subscriptions (I'm fine with 15) and the “Retries” feature. Regarding this feature, it is [specified](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/subscribe-account-activity/guides/activity-retries) that “The Account Activity API provides a retry feature when the client’s web app does not return a ‘success’ 200 response for an account activity webhook event.” 
It clearly states that the event failure concerns the client’s side, not the Twitter side. Considering this issue (my server doesn't receive the webhook at all), there is no guarantee that every event will be delivered even if in a paid plan.

This is a big inconvenience for bots since a button can only be clicked once, so the user must retry the conversation from the beginning (besides the fact that the bot "doesn't work"...)

So my questions are :

- Is anyone here experience this issue ?
- Is this a “bug or a feature” of the free Account Activity API ? I mean, at random the free tier doesn't fire the webhook on purpose (even if it's not specified in the docs) ?
- Is there a way to see or measure the webhook failures Twitter side, via the dashboard for instance ?
- A guess is that the events could be more accurate if the account is verified (with a blue badge) or hit a followers number threshold ? The treatment could be different due to the potential surge of events, so they are monitored with more ressources, thus more reliable ?

I already create a [topic](https://twittercommunity.com/t/inconsistent-webhook-delivery-of-account-activity-api/134166) in the official Twitter forum and there is at least one other person in the same case, but no official answer from Twitter so far.

Thanks a lot !

BR,
Simon

Comment: I can confirm that I have observed the same behavior when working with Twitter's webhooks. A webhook event is missing for about 1 in 10 private messages.

Answer (score 2):

I've got an official answer from Twitter :

> Unfortunately it is not possible to achieve 100% delivery rate when there is only 1 delivery attempt for an event, which is why we have retries (and even then, retries are not a guarantee either). Things can go wrong; maybe internal issues in Twitter Data Centers, routing issues in the internet, hosting issues at your webhook, etc.

So from the time being, it seems that there's not way to have a 100% success delivery when you build a bot on Twitter.

Full answer can be read [here](https://twittercommunity.com/t/inconsistent-webhook-delivery-of-account-activity-api/134166/5).